# How to observe LiveData created by Service from UI/MainActivity/Fragments?

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle, android-livedata, android-service-binding

I have a service that updates data every now and then. I currently use sharedPreferences to store the data and use LocalBroadcast to communicate between the service and UI.

I would like to improve this to use MutableLiveData, something like so.

```
class MyService : Service() {
    private var mMyServiceCreatedData = MutableLiveData<String>()
    private var mData = ""

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        ....
        mData = someData
        mMyServiceCreatedData.postValue(mData)
    }
}
```

I understand there's viewModel but in this case it's the service which generates the data and not a viewModel so I don't know how it works for Service. Is it possible to observe data created from a Service in UI/MainActivity/Fragments?

Comment: Couldnt you just put it into a `companion object` then do `MyService.mMyServiceCreatedData` where you want it?

Comment: @tyczj don't ever do that. That's now how it should be done.

Answer (score 4):

There are many different approaches to this, so I won't go into too much detail; Stack Overflow is not built around that.

LiveData is just a value holder. It is when "observers" come to "observe" your events that you start having to think about Lifecycle.

If you don't like the LocalBroadcast mode, then you could:

1. Service stores the value in a repository instead of emitting/posting the value.
2. Repository emits a `flow` or exposes LiveData (I don't like liveData in repos but that's fine).
3. ViewModel (and UI/Fragment/Act) will eventually subscribe to this Repository (same instance, I assume you have Dependency Injection or pass your references anyway you want), when it's in scope.

This decouples all the pieces and allows them to run independently of each other.

As a last resort, you could always `bind` your service to your activity, but that's -I believe- a different use-case than this.

Comment: For my usecase, use of a repository is an overkill and adds more complexity as my data is just 4 strings to be exact. I've also tried using `` DataStore`` but for some reason data changes in DataStore is not observed in the UI ```GlobalScope.launch {
    dataStoreManager.storeData(someData)
}

dataStoreManager.data1Flow.asLiveData().observe(this, {
})```

Comment: I guess it's better to stay with LocalBroadcast

Comment: To be honest, if you have "4 strings" keep using LocalBroadcast :) You can even use a simple value holder for all 4 strings and broadcast them (all 4) at the same time, once or similar.

Comment: Having to send broadcast from service to UI, listen and act, then send back UI clicks as broadcast from UI to service and then act, code can get quite messy :-) Anyway, thanks for your input, that helps a bunch!

Comment: It can get messy and annoying, but the question then shifts towards the next: Do you really need your service to intercept all these "events"? The service should be used only as the last "resort" of the chain. If your work depends on a UI to be present, then a Service is unlikely to be the best choice, if on the other hand you don't care for the UI, then you shouldn't care for UI Events in your service, those should be handled elsewhere and only service-useful actions should bubble up to it. Perhaps rethink how you're using it may help cancel the code entangle :)

Comment: Hi! I came up here from struggling on a my use case, a bit different than this one, I guess.
I need to collect Flow data from my Room's repo, within a Service, running in foreground, is it a right pattern? Here is my question on what I'm trying to implement: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72621674/workmanager-in-android-to-handle-producer-consumer-pattern-for-data-received-in
Sometimes "collect" I used within a CoroutineScope (seems when I lock device's screen) stops listen for a while, until user's input
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @riccardogabellone it seems adequate.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fixed it.

1. Create MyApp class which extends Application
2. Create instance of MyApp

   private static MyApp myApp;
   public static MyApp getInstance() {
   return myApp;
   }
3. Access MyApp from your service/fragment/anywhere you want.
4. Create instance of your model class in MyApp.

   public ViewModel model;
   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
   super.onCreate();
   model = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(ViewModel.class);
5. To access your model

```
 MyApp.getInstance().model.doYourWork();
```

6. Using this you can update your model and update ui.