# WorkManager in Android to handle producer/consumer pattern for data received in FCM

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging, producer-consumer, android-workmanager

I'd like to know a workaround to create a producer/consumer pattern in my Android application:

I have a dedicated device having a thermal printer, this app receives push notifications from **FCM** and print a receipt as soon as they arrive. Here it is the issue: multiple notifications at same time are not managed well, some are printed and some other not.

Printing is a call to `startActivity(...)` with an `Intent` containing an `ACTION_VIEW` with a Uri to open that allows printer service (external and not managed by me) to wake up.

So, I thought to create the well known producer/consumer pattern to enqueue all my `Intent` objects instead of calling startActivity inside **FCM**'s `onMessageReceived(...)`. How can I achieve that? What kind of service should it be implemented to consume this queue and send synchronously prints through these Intent*s*?

I read docs on **[WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/define-work)** APIs and I'm trying to write something like this below:

`MyFirebaseMessagingService.kt`

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {

        remoteMessage.data.isNotEmpty().let { _ ->
            try{
                val content =
                    remoteMessage.data["content"]?.let { it1 -> Json.parseToJsonElement(it1).jsonObject }
                content?.let { it ->
                    val title = it["title"]?.toString() ?: "Title example"
                    val body = it["message"]?.toString() ?: "Msg example"
                    val pushId = it["notificationId"]?.toString() ?: "42"
                    val data = it["data"]?.jsonObject                    

                    val intent = sendToPrinterIntent(data)
                    sendNotification(..., intent)

                    //startActivity(intent) //TODO add producer-consumer queue
                    PrintingWorker.enqueueWork(this, intent)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception){
                Log.d("pushMessage", "Error in json data: $e")
            }
        }
    }

    private fun sendToPrinterIntent(data: JsonObject?): Intent {
        return data?.let {            
            val body = getBody(it)
            val uri = "customschema://q?text=$body"
            return Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri))
        } ?: Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("customschema://q?text="))
    }

    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        Log.d("FCMtoken", "Refreshed token: $token")
    }

    private fun sendNotification(
        messageBody: String,
        messageTitle: String,
        pushId: Int,
        pendingIntent: Intent
    ) {
        ...
    }

}
```

`PrintingWorker.kt`

```
class PrintingWorker(private val appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) :
    CoroutineWorker(appContext, workerParams) {

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        //calls start activity and waits for it to finish
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
           //appContext.startActivity()
           workerParams.inputData.keyValueMap.forEach {
              println("key: ${it.key} value: ${it.value}")
           }
           //setForeground()
           Result.success()
        }
    }

    override suspend fun getForegroundInfo(): ForegroundInfo {
        return try {
            ForegroundInfo(NOTIFICATION_ID,createNotification())
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            ForegroundInfo(NOTIFICATION_ID,Notification()) //example: can be ignored
        }
    }

    private fun createNotification(): Notification {
        return NotificationCompat...
    }

    companion object{
        val TAG = "PrintingWorker"
        val NOTIFICATION_ID = 4242

        fun enqueueWork(context: Context, workData: Intent) {
            
            val workRequest = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(PrintingWorker::class.java)
                .setExpedited(OutOfQuotaPolicy.RUN_AS_NON_EXPEDITED_WORK_REQUEST)
                .setInputData(workDataOf(Pair("printingIntent",workData)))
                .build()
            WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(workRequest)
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in `PrintingWorker`, I'm not sure on how to let the WorkManager schedules and consumes the enqueued Intents. Idea of using this APIs is to allow consuming queue even device reboots, for example.

Any suggestions?

**[EDIT]** After reviewing possible solutions, I plan to achieve my goal by using `Room` + *Foreground* `Service`:
idea is to create entries in a table of the `Room` DB when a notification arrives in **FCM**'s `onReceiveMessage` -> then a `ForegroundService` consume entries (deleting one at a time after printing data in it) by using `Flow` or something like that. Is it a more suitable solution? If yes, what should it be the right procedure to use `Flow` (or `LiveData`) to do so, avoiding unwanted results?

Comment: When you receive a msg, save it in a Room Table, have a boolean to indicate if it's consumed or not yet. Then have your printing service periodically check (or ultimately be awaken by FCM, or both) to check if there are pending jobs in the Room table/queue. I suggest you maybe have 2 booleans, and mark them as "in progress" while you're printing and preparing, only delete (or mark them as consumed) *after* you're done with it. (or remove them/move them to a "log" table for archive/storage). But yes, that's a more suitable solution.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to convert the `Bundle` from `Intent workData` to `Data data` ...with [`Data.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/Data.Builder).

Comment: thanks! just edited adding correct parameter to setInputData(). Do you know how it can be consumed by doWork() ?

Comment: I don't understand the question and it's unclear where `Intent` even comes from. Usually one would send a [data message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages) with an ID and then trigger `SyncAdaper`.

Comment: did not know about that, let me understand: fcm does already provide a way to achieve this?

Comment: @riccardogabellone can you please provide the way how you have achieved this??

Comment: @TanishqChawda Haven't you read the answer? It obviously tells how.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I have got it btw Thankyou!!